# How to ensure an online payment is executed only once?

Tags: javascript, php, transactions, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I developed and I maintain a website for a client of mine that has online payments.

For the most part it uses the payment gateway provided by the client's bank Banorte in Mexico. The issue I am having is that on some occasions the payments get executed twice. I am not sure if the user double clicks or there's some other issue, currently still trying to find out what happens, but the last case that this happened the space between the payments was around 2 minutes. The other issue regarding this is that the product is limited to 1 per person since it's an event access.

I have a form that gets the card information and on click I do the following (using Foundation 6):

```js
var cardSubmit = false;
$(document).on("submit", "#card-form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(cardSubmit) {
        $("#process").addClass("loading");
        $("#card-form button[type='submit']").prop("disabled", true).html("Processing...");
        setTimeout(function() {
            e.currentTarget.submit();
        }, 2500);
    }
})

$(document).on("formvalid.zf.abide", "#card-form", function() {
    cardSubmit = true;
})

$(document).on("forminvalid.zf.abide", "#card-form", function() {
    cardSubmit = false;
})
```

The `.loading` class adds an `::after` element that goes on top of everything and besides I disable the button. This is to ensure that the user can't click on the button again. I am not sure if under this scenario a double click is possible.

After submitting (code reduced for obvious reasons), I do the following:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://via.banorte.com:443']);

$parametros = [...]; // information required for the payment

$postQuery = http_build_query($parametros);
$contentLength = strlen($postQuery);

$resultadoPago = $client->post('/payw2', [
    'query' => $parametros,
]);
$headersPago = $resultadoPago->getHeaders();

if ($headersPago['RESULTADO_PAYW'][0] == 'A') {
    // This runs if the response is Authorized
    // The first thing I do here is create the new transaction and mark it as paid
    // Then I do some more stuff and finally redirect to a thank you page
}
```

Then if the user goes to the product I check if there are already transactions that have this same product so that I don't allow the user to try and buy it again. So that leads me to believe that the double payment occurs in the same window and something fails in the process.

Is there a way to guarantee that I execute this only once? Or am I always dependent on the response of the payment gateway? I was thinking of adding the same check as mentioned in the previous paragraph, but not sure if the page is refreshing or the user is refreshing the page.

Comment: I would also return false at the end of your submit event handler that will also prevent form submission.  I have had double click issues with links for example that can get around `preventDefault` by itself.  I always return false on links or disable them via element callbacks in the HTML.  Personally if JS was required to submit the form, I would just use a button instead.

Comment: I once had a co-worker who had a defective mouse that double clicked everything.  It's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding the true or false to a data attribute and make sure the target was the actual form. I would not trust e.currentTarget to still be the same after 2.5 seconds

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#card-form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(this).data("cardSubmit")) return ;
  let DOMForm = this;
  $("#process").addClass("loading");
  $("button[type='submit']",this).prop("disabled", true).html("Processing...");
  setTimeout(function() {
    DOMForm.submit();
    $(DOMForm).data("cardSubmit",false); 
  }, 2500);
})

$(document).on("formvalid.zf.abide", "#card-form", function() {
  $(this).data("cardSubmit",true);
})

$(document).on("forminvalid.zf.abide", "#card-form", function() {
  $(this).data("cardSubmit",false);
})
```

Comment: But even if the `e.target` isn't the same wouldn't that imply that no payment would be attempted at all? Also, the variable I use is only modifed by the specific form submit attempt. Do you consider it's not trustworthy?

Comment: I added cardSubmit = false in the timeout. then you can reset that in a new attempt or not as you wish

Comment: Do you think lowering the timeout could be positive, I added it so that the user felt something was being processed, because it normally runs pretty fast.

Comment: Absolutely or you actually submit using ajax and tell them

Answer (score 0):

I think the deeper issue is your validation of whether a product has been purchased. I dont see a reason why double-clicking would make a product be purchased twice if you keep track of the purchases and products in a database.

If you do manage a database, you could keep track of the purchases yourself and validate against the database on each call if the product is available. If available, then process the payment and update your database accordingly with the payment service response. Finally, return the status of the purchase to your frontend.

Comment: I actually mention this, but I am not sure why I didn't include it. I do validate it in a previous step, but not in the payment step which could be the most important in this case.

Comment: a function that validates that the product is truly available should be around your payment process code. im guessing you already have that code to display available products only to your users. use it to validate again before the purchase.